# Normalize values in data frame given unsorted other constraints

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
            counter leg_rate pose_rate component    approach      rmse
0   proc/stat-stime        d         d      test    Baseline  1.583097
1   proc/stat-stime        d         r      test  AEW - MTEN  0.516108
2   proc/stat-stime        d         d      test        ASDF  0.705861
3   proc/stat-stime        r         r      test        ASDF  0.345816
4   proc/stat-utime        d         r      test    Baseline  1.128632
5   proc/stat-stime        d         r      test    Baseline  1.579803
6   proc/stat-stime        r         r      test    Baseline  1.345895
7   proc/stat-utime        r         r      test  AEW - MTEN  0.187236
8   proc/stat-utime        d         d      test    Baseline  1.193776
9   proc/stat-stime        r         d      test        ASDF  0.014975
10  proc/stat-utime        r         r      test        ASDF  0.985493
11  proc/stat-utime        r         d      test  AEW - MTEN  0.897336
12  proc/stat-stime        r         d      test    Baseline  1.415103
13  proc/stat-utime        r         d      test    Baseline  1.724266
14  proc/stat-utime        r         r      test    Baseline  1.294654
15  proc/stat-utime        d         d      test  AEW - MTEN  0.263845
16  proc/stat-utime        r         d      test        ASDF  0.497368
17  proc/stat-stime        d         d      test  AEW - MTEN  0.143402
18  proc/stat-utime        d         r      test  AEW - MTEN  0.233437
19  proc/stat-stime        r         d      test  AEW - MTEN  0.431739
20  proc/stat-utime        d         r      test        ASDF  0.002475
21  proc/stat-stime        d         r      test        ASDF  0.331700
22  proc/stat-stime        r         r      test  AEW - MTEN  0.985123
23  proc/stat-utime        d         d      test        ASDF  0.464989
```

I want to normalize `rmse` by dividing it with the values from the `approach` called `Baseline`. In the end there should be a new column `rmse-norm` with the respective normalized values. All other columns basically provide a context that needs to be matched when dividing `rmse`. That means the row

```
1   proc/stat-stime        d         r      test  AEW - MTEN  0.516108
```

needs to be divided by the row with matching other columns

```
5   proc/stat-stime        d         r      test    Baseline  1.579803
```

There will always be a matching row from the `Baseline` approach.

I have tried various things with `groupby` and using indexes for the other columns, but due to the unknown ordering of columns I couldn't come up with something concise that assigns the correct values with the right ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
#filter all rows with Baseline to `MultiIndex` `Series`
cols = ['counter','leg_rate','pose_rate','component']
s = df[df.approach == 'Baseline'].set_index(cols)['rmse']
print (s)
counter          leg_rate  pose_rate  component
proc/stat-stime  d         d          test         1.583097
proc/stat-utime  d         r          test         1.128632
proc/stat-stime  d         r          test         1.579803
                 r         r          test         1.345895
proc/stat-utime  d         d          test         1.193776
proc/stat-stime  r         d          test         1.415103
proc/stat-utime  r         d          test         1.724266
                           r          test         1.294654
Name: rmse, dtype: float64
```

```
#sorting for matching, because set_index sort index
df = df.sort_values(cols)
#divide by s, output to numpy array for assign to rmse column
df['rmse'] = df.set_index(cols)['rmse'].div(s).values
#sort index to original unsorted df
print (df.sort_index())
            counter leg_rate pose_rate component    approach      rmse
0   proc/stat-stime        d         d      test    Baseline  1.000000
1   proc/stat-stime        d         r      test  AEW - MTEN  0.326691
2   proc/stat-stime        d         d      test        ASDF  0.445873
3   proc/stat-stime        r         r      test        ASDF  0.256941
4   proc/stat-utime        d         r      test    Baseline  1.000000
5   proc/stat-stime        d         r      test    Baseline  1.000000
6   proc/stat-stime        r         r      test    Baseline  1.000000
7   proc/stat-utime        r         r      test  AEW - MTEN  0.144622
8   proc/stat-utime        d         d      test    Baseline  1.000000
9   proc/stat-stime        r         d      test        ASDF  0.010582
10  proc/stat-utime        r         r      test        ASDF  0.761202
11  proc/stat-utime        r         d      test  AEW - MTEN  0.520416
12  proc/stat-stime        r         d      test    Baseline  1.000000
13  proc/stat-utime        r         d      test    Baseline  1.000000
14  proc/stat-utime        r         r      test    Baseline  1.000000
15  proc/stat-utime        d         d      test  AEW - MTEN  0.221017
16  proc/stat-utime        r         d      test        ASDF  0.288452
17  proc/stat-stime        d         d      test  AEW - MTEN  0.090583
18  proc/stat-utime        d         r      test  AEW - MTEN  0.206832
19  proc/stat-stime        r         d      test  AEW - MTEN  0.305094
20  proc/stat-utime        d         r      test        ASDF  0.002193
21  proc/stat-stime        d         r      test        ASDF  0.209963
22  proc/stat-stime        r         r      test  AEW - MTEN  0.731946
23  proc/stat-utime        d         d      test        ASDF  0.389511
```

Another solution with `groupby` and custom function `f`:

```
def f(x):
    x.rmse = x['rmse'] / x.loc[x['approach'] == 'Baseline', 'rmse'].item()
    return x

df = df.groupby(['counter','leg_rate','pose_rate','component']).apply(f)
print (df)
            counter leg_rate pose_rate component    approach      rmse
0   proc/stat-stime        d         d      test    Baseline  1.000000
1   proc/stat-stime        d         r      test  AEW - MTEN  0.326691
2   proc/stat-stime        d         d      test        ASDF  0.445873
3   proc/stat-stime        r         r      test        ASDF  0.256941
4   proc/stat-utime        d         r      test    Baseline  1.000000
5   proc/stat-stime        d         r      test    Baseline  1.000000
6   proc/stat-stime        r         r      test    Baseline  1.000000
7   proc/stat-utime        r         r      test  AEW - MTEN  0.144622
8   proc/stat-utime        d         d      test    Baseline  1.000000
9   proc/stat-stime        r         d      test        ASDF  0.010582
10  proc/stat-utime        r         r      test        ASDF  0.761202
11  proc/stat-utime        r         d      test  AEW - MTEN  0.520416
12  proc/stat-stime        r         d      test    Baseline  1.000000
13  proc/stat-utime        r         d      test    Baseline  1.000000
14  proc/stat-utime        r         r      test    Baseline  1.000000
15  proc/stat-utime        d         d      test  AEW - MTEN  0.221017
16  proc/stat-utime        r         d      test        ASDF  0.288452
17  proc/stat-stime        d         d      test  AEW - MTEN  0.090583
18  proc/stat-utime        d         r      test  AEW - MTEN  0.206832
19  proc/stat-stime        r         d      test  AEW - MTEN  0.305094
20  proc/stat-utime        d         r      test        ASDF  0.002193
21  proc/stat-stime        d         r      test        ASDF  0.209963
22  proc/stat-stime        r         r      test  AEW - MTEN  0.731946
23  proc/stat-utime        d         d      test        ASDF  0.389511
```

Comment: I tried this, but this kills the approach column, which I need.

Comment: Still looks wrong. Baseline / Baseline should always be 1

Comment: Which duplicates? When observing all columns, there should not be any duplicates.

Comment: For the groupby solution: how to get back the approach column?

Comment: Please check eited answer.